# should I pass query parameters in the url or in the payload?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Suppose I have a REST endpoint like this :

```
http://server/users/query
```

And I have parameters in my query : `age, city, country`

I want to do a GET request with those parameters.

Should I better pass the parameters in the `url` ? Or put something like this in the payload of my GET request.

```
"query": {
    "age": "something",
    "city": "something",
    "country": "something"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my understanding, you have a *collection of users* and you want to get a representation of it. You should consider *query parameters* to filter your collection, as following:

```
http://[host]/api/users?age=something&city=something&country=something
```

And avoid `GET` requests with a payload. See the quote from the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1):

> A payload within a `GET` request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a `GET` request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET): GET requests (typically) don't have bodies so use the query parameters or the path.

If you are making requests to a server you should instead read the documentation of it's API.